# Manipulate multiple csv files from R in the same time with the same structure

Tags: r, csv

I have a set of csv.files. Can I do operations in the same time with R?, for example select the same columns, delete colums?

Greetings
Mark

Comment: Yes, place it in a list and use `lapply` to loop through the list and then access the same columns, delete etc.  But, first you need to show a small reproducible example

Comment: I am working with functional data, I need transform a list that you have in each component one variable, one column of one list. Are you know , faster alternative?